# Get user roles via Keycloak API

Tags: python, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to set up a field in UserInfo that contains a list of the user's roles. First, I created a role in the Realm and added it to the user:

[image]

Then I configured the role mapping in the Client:

[image]

After that, I get user information through the [python-keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) library:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

KEYCLOAK_OPENID = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url='https://keycloak.com/auth/',
    client_id='django-keycloak',
    realm_name='test_realm',
    client_secret_key='client_secret_key',
)

access_token = 'token-asdadad'
userinfo = KEYCLOAK_OPENID.userinfo(access_token)
```

But the 'role' field is not there:

```
{'sub': 'sdfsdfsdfsd-fba8-4718-819c-sdfsdfd',
 'email_verified': True,
 'name': 'Alexander Test',
 'preferred_username': 'alexander',
 'given_name': 'Alexander',
 'locale': 'en',
 'family_name': 'Test',
 'email': 'alex@email.com'}
```

How to correctly configure the Client so that the 'Roles' field is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Go to Client Scopes Menu from the realm 'test_realm';
2. Select roles;
3. Go to Mappers;
4. Click on the Mapper 'realm roles'
5. There enable the option 'Add to userinfo'
6. Save and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is complicated steps.
Answer first: GET {{keycloak_url}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users/{{alexander_user_id}}/role-mappings

it can get the alexander's role
Example GET call by Postman
[image]

it matched UI of Keycloak
[image]

Tricky parts is how to get the user ID by API
From the Get users list, need to assign alex's user id in Tests section via environment variable in Postman.
It needs to call before get the role of Alex.
[image]

You, I attached whole steps by API
from create realm, create client/role/Alex, role mapping and get the Alex role information.
Enjoy Keycloak API programming. (oops! no way to attach JSON file in here, sorry)