# keycloak 23, testing token api, always getting 401Unauthorized

Tags: postman, keycloak

im trying to implement keycloak with a spring project

This is the keycloak version
[image]

I made a new realm and created a client and one role,

the client name is test_client
[image]

the role that I created is named admin
[image]

this is the user that I'm trying to generate a token for

[image]

he has the admin role , and I'm pretty sure of the user credentials

I tried to test the token endpoint in postman and I always get the 401 error, I tried installing keycloak with a zip folder and with docker, both same error, I create a lot of new reals and users and clients and still the same issue, [image]

and here is the keycloak logs,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`admin` is just a name you have to add an associate role as admin's role.

##### #1 add `admin` role with associate roles

[image]

##### #2 Assign `admin` role to user

[image]

##### #3 Get user's token by Postman

URL

```
POST http://localhost:8080/realms/if-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

```
client_id  : admin-cli
username   : [user-name]
password   : [user-password] 
grant_type : password
```

[image]

##### More detail user token and role

[Assign a client scope to user with a specific role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75508151/keycloak-assign-a-client-scope-to-user-with-a-specific-role/75513974#75513974)

[Get user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404975/get-user-roles-via-keycloak-api/72412169#72412169)

[User's realm role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244798/problem-in-assigning-roles-to-user-while-creating-it-with-post-http-request/74250457#74250457)

[Get User list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606410/which-api-should-use-to-get-user-permissions-list-by-userid-with-keycloak-admin/73607156#73607156)

---

##### Alternative Way by import

Save as `example-realm.json`

```json
{
  "realm": "my-realm",
  "enabled": true,
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "registrationAllowed": true,
  "privateKey": "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",
  "publicKey": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrVrCuTtArbgaZzL1hvh0xtL5mc7o0NqPVnYXkLvgcwiC3BjLGw1tGEGoJaXDuSaRllobm53JBhjx33UNv+5z/UMG4kytBWxheNVKnL6GgqlNabMaFfPLPCF8kAgKnsi79NMo+n6KnSY8YeUmec/p2vjO2NjsSAVcWEQMVhJ31LwIDAQAB",
  "requiredCredentials": ["password"],
  "roles": {
    "realm": [
      {
        "name": "offline_access",
        "description": "${role_offline-access}",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "attributes": {}
      },
      {
        "name": "default-roles-if-realm",
        "description": "${role_default-roles}",
        "composite": true,
        "composites": {
          "realm": ["offline_access", "uma_authorization"],
          "client": {
            "account": ["manage-account", "view-profile"]
          }
        },
        "clientRole": false,
        "attributes": {}
      },
      {
        "name": "admin",
        "description": "",
        "composite": true,
        "composites": {
          "client": {
            "realm-management": [
              "manage-clients",
              "create-client",
              "realm-admin",
              "manage-realm",
              "manage-users"
            ]
          }
        },
        "clientRole": false,
        "attributes": {}
      },
      {
        "name": "uma_authorization",
        "description": "${role_uma_authorization}",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": false,
        "attributes": {}
      }
    ]
  },

  "users": [
    {
      "username": "admin",
      "enabled": true,
      "credentials": [
        {
          "type": "password",
          "value": "1234"
        }
      ],
      "realmRoles": [ "admin" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Create `realm` from this `JSON` file

[image]

Result

[image]

##### Import Collection by Postman

Save as `1-1-demo.postman_collection.json`

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "b1c61b66-c3ca-4df8-8f13-45c0be111fab",
        "name": "1-1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Admin token",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "postman.setEnvironmentVariable(\"admin-token\", jsonData.access_token);\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "client_id",
                            "value": "admin-cli",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "admin",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "1234",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "password",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "openid",
                            "type": "text",
                            "disabled": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "port": "8080",
                    "path": [
                        "realms",
                        "my-realm",
                        "protocol",
                        "openid-connect",
                        "token"
                    ]
                },
                "description": "Obtain UAT = user access token from a user in realm"
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Import that file from Postman

[image]
Select `1-1-demo` collection

`Admin token` Request

Press <kbd>Send</kbd> button

[image]

Comment: i did all of that and still the same problem for me, can you come discord or something to help me

Comment: I added `Alternative Way by import`, can you follow that step?

Comment: It worked , thank you , but can you tell me what is the difference between the my config and ur config ?

Comment: Try delete your "if-realm" realm by master and change the  `example-realm.json` file. The "realm":  from "my-realm" to "if-realm". Then import it. It is re-produce UI steps. I think you missed my Some UI steps.

Comment: Can you give me up vote too? I will give 10 more points, Thanks!